# ASP.NET MVC core POST Request not converting JSON data to Model

Tags: c#, post, vue.js, axios, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a model that I serialize to the screen and use with Vue.js.  After screen/model changes I am using axios to perform a POST request back into my ASP.NET Core (2.0) Controller.  So far every combination of tries results in all null values when evaluating my custom model in my Controller.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Model:

```
[Serializable]
public class ClientsWebsite
{
    [Key]
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string CustomSiteScript { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public string SliderImagePath { get; set; }
    public string MessageHeader { get; set; }
    public string CallToActionMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Vue and POST Call:

```
var sliderApp = new Vue({
    el: '#sliderApp',
    data: {
        ClientsWebsite: [],
        axajLoaded: false,
        picked: []
    },
    created: function () {
        getUserSettings()
    }
})

function saveCustomSettings() {
    axios.post('/Slider/Slider/SaveCustomSettings', {
        vm: sliderApp.ClientsWebsite
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveCustomSettings(ClientsWebsite vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //stuff...
        }

        return "Success";
    }
```

I have also tried using JSON.stringify in my JavaScript POST call, no changes.

Results of the POST Header Request Payload:

```
{"ClientsWebsite":{"ClientID":"6056e4a8-32a8-4042-b750-50c609edf140","CustomSiteScript":"someScriptHere","WebsiteName":"Blah.com","FormName":"Contact1","SliderImagePath":"ContactUs3","MessageHeader":"Hello, please send us a message","CallToActionMessage":"We will respond ASAP!!!!!"}}
```

UPDATE:
The solution came from a combination of both the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a object wrapped around your model:

```
{"ClientsWebsite":{"ClientID":"6056e4a8-32a8-4042-b750-50c609edf140","CustomSiteScript":"someScriptHere","WebsiteName":"Blah.com","FormName":"Contact1","SliderImagePath":"ContactUs3","MessageHeader":"Hello, please send us a message","CallToActionMessage":"We will respond ASAP!!!!!"}}
```

Remove it:

```
{"ClientID":"6056e4a8-32a8-4042-b750-50c609edf140","CustomSiteScript":"someScriptHere","WebsiteName":"Blah.com","FormName":"Contact1","SliderImagePath":"ContactUs3","MessageHeader":"Hello, please send us a message","CallToActionMessage":"We will respond ASAP!!!!!"}
```

For your function:

```
function saveCustomSettings() {
axios.post('/Slider/Slider/SaveCustomSettings', 
    sliderApp.ClientsWebsite
)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Comment: Changing the POST request removed "ClientWebsite" from the string.  I compared the GET request object loaded onto the screen and the POST request per your changes and the objects are exactly the same.  However in the controller, all my objects are still null.

Comment: If you want to change the post-Request itself, you have to remove the first and the last brace too.

Comment: The request is fine and matches how you show above now.

Comment: Do you still have vm==null?

Comment: vm is not Null, but all the properties within vm are still null.

Comment: Yes I, missed that detail.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Nikolaus said, try adding [FromBody] before ClientsWebsite vm.

```
[HttpPost]
public string SaveCustomSettings([FromBody]ClientsWebsite vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //stuff...
    }

    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: Both of your answers were the solution!